# High-level strategy for distinguishing a regular string from invalid JSON (ie. JSON-like string detection)

Tags: algorithms, parsing, data-structures, json

**Disclaimer On Absence of Code:**

I have no code to post because I haven't started writing; was looking for more theoretical guidance as I doubt I'll have trouble coding it but am pretty befuddled on what approach(es) would yield best results. I'm not *seeking* any code, either, though; just direction.

**Dilemma**

I'm toying with adding a "magic method"-style feature to a UI I'm building for a client, and it would require intelligently detecting whether or not a string was meant to be JSON as against a simple string.

I had considered these general ideas:

1. Look for a sort of arbitrarily-determined acceptable ratio of the frequency of JSON-like syntax (ie. regex to find strings separated by colons; look for colons between curly-braces, etc.) to the number of quote-encapsulated strings + `null`s, `bool`s and `int`s/`float`s. But the smaller the data set, the more fickle this would get
2. look for key identifiers like opening and closing curly braces... not sure if there even *are* more easy identifiers, and this doesn't appeal anyway because it's so prescriptive about the kinds of mistakes it could find
3. try incrementally parsing chunks, as those between curly braces, and seeing what proportion of these fractional statements turn out to be valid JSON; this seems like it would suffer less than (1) from smaller datasets, but would probably be much more processing-intensive, and very susceptible to a missing or inverted brace

Just curious if the computational folks or algorithm pros out there had any approaches in mind that my semantics-oriented brain might have missed.

PS: It occurs to me that natural language processing, about which I am totally ignorant, might be a cool approach; but, *if* NLP is a good strategy here, it sort of doesn't matter because I have zero experience with it and don't have time to learn & then implement/ this feature isn't worth it to the client.

Comment: No, maybe I should clarify—I was hoping this was the appropriate place (as against Overflow) to discuss the high-level approach. Implementing I can probably do fine, *what* exactly to implement is where I feel ill-equipped.

Comment: Haha I can add in my regex for detecting *valid* JSON in the first place (j/k)? :P But understood, I'd actually appreciate knowing where the Stack-community directs their abstracta. :)

Comment: To explain the above: this question had gotten migrated from codereview.stackexchange; the above had been responses to comments essentially debating the appropriate Stack Community for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The real answer ("tell between **invalid** JSON and a string")

For a lot of obvious reasons we're not going to come up with a definite answer - we can at best hope to determine an index that will tell us whether a string *might have been* JSON.

The best approach I can think of is to use something like the Levenshtein algorithm, with this twist: we have no "B string", but rather we start parsing the candidate string and modify it as soon as we hit an invalid character.

To do this, we can use a JSON streaming parser (state-based). Let's say we parse

```
{ "key": value" }
```

then the parser will find the 'v' and choke. At that point we can try deleting the character, or adding one of several possible valid characters for that state and recurse.

Any branch can be abandoned as soon as the distance to valid JSON for that branch exceeds a minimum, if one has been found so far, or according to some heuristics (e.g. no more than four consecutive ['s, and so on), or as soon as it exceeds a maximum allowed distance (say, 5). This last condition is probably essential to avoid snowballing.

A drawback of this approach is that some solutions would require backtracking:

```
{ "key": "value }
```

would be accepted up to the end, then a missing " would be added, and finally a missing }, getting a valid JSON:

```
{ "key": "value }"}
```

with a distance of 2 (two additions). Perhaps some fast heuristic for backtracking can be found (e.g. when in "wait-for-end-quote", backtrack until the first non-"special" character, and ignore whitespaces).

An important element to assess the viability of a solution would be **how is this invalid JSON generated**, i.e., is it a truncated JSON? Are some characters damaged? has it some sort of basic structure which is always the same?

## User-generated JSON

As per comment, this JSON may be the result of an attempt of hand-building JSON. This on one hand is *bad* since human beings are very close to a random source when we're talking about errors :-). On the other hand it may be good since the JSON is probably "almost good JSON" with possibly only a few errors: commas left out or added in,

```
{ "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "email": "jdoe@email.com", }
```

Indeed, we might find it useful to at least preprocess the string to remove some common errors:

",\s*} --> "}                       # Extra comma due to copy-paste
   (")\s*[:;.]*\s*("[^"]*"\s*:)     # Forgot or mistyped a comma between 1 and 2

and since (hopefully) square and curly braces won't appear inside keys or values, we can try and balance them, and/or use them as guidance: e.g. if the curly braces are balanced, assume they're okay and do not add or remove any of them. This has to be weighted against users' error capacity - if they are liable to *totally misplace* a closing curly brace, then we can't rely on balancing.

(Of course, we can't do anything against a *malicious* user intentionally feeding malformed JSON designed to either trick the system, or even cause a denial of service through some expression requiring exponential time computation).

At that point we could instead, as you suggested, consider the frequency of JSON control characters, or try recognizing JSON subsequences. This has to be compared against whatever **else** might come in in that field.

## The bad answer ("tell between **valid** JSON and a string")

In the general case you *cannot* distinguish with 100% accuracy between strings and JSONs because, while not all JSONs are valid strings, **all valid strings are valid JSONs**. The encoding of a bare string is that string.

So upon receiving `"Hello, world"`, any function would return that this is *both* a valid string and a valid JSON. Which should it choose?

Otherwise, distinguishing is pretty straightforward. Plug the JSON engine of your choice and try decoding the string as JSON. If you can, that is a JSON string. If you can't, it's a text string:

```
-- pseudo code
with ( JSON.decode(myString) ) {
    if (.isNull()) {
        -- Error. Not valid JSON, so it must be a String.
        return "String"
    }
    -- It is a valid JSON, but a String is that, too.
    if (.type().equals("String")) {
        -- Could return either, too, depending.
        return "Ambiguous"
    }
}
return "JSON"
```

This is surely not as efficient as a function that just *checks* the grammar constraints (you can find the schemas on the [home page](http://www.json.org/)), but it's a lot more maintainable. You can probably get a FSM by boiling dry the code of a [streaming parser](https://gist.github.com/creationix/5992451) and removing all data emission, just returning "true" or "false" (a processing error meaning it's not valid JSON).

Comment: There are not "for different flavors of JSON" (what ever you mean with that). Both keys and strings must use double quotes in valid JSON. It's possible that some JSON parsers are more relaxed, but that doesn't change [the standard](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Good point. I had linked the standard myself, but while I've always used double quotes, it has happened to me more than once to *receive* unquoted (i.e. Javascript-literal) object keys. I had assumed it was a deprecated, but legal, format; but you are correct, and it is not. Thanks!

Comment: Also, though I appreciate the effort, it's not clear to me that your answer responds to the need, which is not to find valid JSON but rather distinguish invalid-but-JSON-like-text from regular or other text.

Comment: You know what: I'm a *moron*. I had completely overlooked the *invalid* part, even though you **had** clearly specified it. Working to amend answer...

Comment: Ha—what you call "moron" I call ADHD. This is really informative, and also a little over my head, but learning is the point. I can go learn what a "Levenshtein algorithm" is, you use phrases like "write a fast heuristic for.." This isn't jargon, yes? You just mean write a (probably recursive) function whose operations put said heuristic into effect, yes? Also, *great* question re: nature of the invalidity. User-error is what I'm expecting; users who attempt to write these documents by hand rather than using my UI—given that constraint, would you prefer any strategy over another?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is a JSON sniffer. Something to look at a string and make a heuristic guess. So what to look for and how to look?

First off, a JSON parser is pretty useless. You call that *after* you've guess it's probably JSON.

I can think of three approaches.

1. Smoking gun. If the string has JSON or json-schema.org in it, that's a match. Maybe there are some other common words you might know of.
2. Regex it. Think up some regexes that would be highly likely to be matched. If over half the lines match one or more suitable regexes it's a match.
3. Tokenise it. JSON typically has *lots* of individual quoted strings, numbers, commas, brackets, braces and colons. Any string that is over 50% made up of those tokens is a match. (Make sure you don't let an unmatched quote swallow the whole string.)

Your suggestions could work too, but I think mine are simpler.

I've used sniffing code in the past and it's surprisingly easy to get it right most of the time. The mistakes are usually when you get (say) a text message with a piece of JSON quoted in it. You can't win them all.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what I was after. I have no background here; where do your choices of 50% come from? For my part, the math is overwhelmingly where I have the least background. Is it just that it's the threshold whereby the guess becomes better than chance?

Comment: Fair question. The 50% is a classification heuristic, intended to divide sniffed text into "most likely JSON" and "probably not JSON". This is a starting point, but then you need test data to see whether it should really be higher or lower.